# Receive an integer or a list of integers with the same parameter

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, javabeans

I have a problem. I am writing a restful API. It is possible to add/remove Items to/from a group. To do that I have to send a POST-Request to a specific URL. The request is shown below. This works already. But I have a requirement that makes me despair. It should be possible to send an integer OR a list of integer in the JSON request. But the parameter names should be the same.

```
{
"add": "10",
"remove": "100"
}
```

But this request should be possible to.

```
{
"add": [
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13
],
"remove": "100"
}
```

I tried, to solve my problem with different setters like below.

```
public class GroupDiff {
// TODO
private List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public List<Integer> getAdd() {
    return add;
}
public void setAdd(List<Integer> add) {
    this.add = add;
}
public void setAdd(int add) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     list.add(add);
    this.add = list;
}
public List<Integer> getRemove() {
    return remove;
}
public void setRemove(List<Integer> remove) {
    this.remove = remove;
}

public void setRemove(int remove) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     list.add(remove);
    this.remove = list;
}
```

But I always receive the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "add": net.erouting.type.GroupDiff#setAdd(1 params) vs net.erouting.type.GroupDiff#setAdd(1 params)

My question is:
How can I solve my problem, that it is possible both an integer and a list of integers by firing a JSON request to my server.

We are using Spring and Hibernate.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you try to pass an array of integer instead of `List<Integer>`? I mean to use as `add` and `remove` not `List<Integer>` but `Integer[] add` and `Integer[] remove` and the same change will be made in your setters and getters

Comment: The resource should be accessible either way without the operator overloading.

Comment: If you remove the setter for `add(int)`, wouldn't Spring try to convert, in the case `"add": "10"`, the single value to a List of one item and provide it to the other setter (List)?

Comment: @emka86 so I tried your idea. Bu it doesn't help me. I can only receive arrays. When I send a single integer i get this Error message: 
 org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer[] out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1b44f637; line: 2, column: 4] (through reference chain: net.erouting.type.GroupDiff["add"])

Comment: @ring0 No it doesn't work. I get this error message: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@602b8db7; line: 2, column: 5] (through reference chain: net.erouting.type.GroupDiff["add"])

Comment: Argh - I call that a bug (in Json). If you cannot change the parameters names, I'd try (but unlikely to work) to change the `add(int)` type to `add(float)` and do a conversion then, just in case ...

Comment: @EvilKarter can't you just send single int as `{ "add": [ 10 ] ...` ? Won't it work?

Comment: That would be great indeed. Btw do you have the [latest JSON code](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)?

Comment: Also maybe by choosing the appropriate [type annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/JacksonAnnotations)?

Comment: @ring0 thank you for your help. We are using jersey-json version 1.12 and i don't know which annotation could help me to solve this problem. I'm going to use the solution proposed by emka86.

Comment: If you can change the prototypes, force parameters to be a list, use @emka86 workaround. Having a look at the Json code would give hints about annotations for both types, and be certainly plenty of valuable knowledge you could use later on. This is the problem with some of Java layers added on top of Spring: thanks to the language and the environment, programmers do usually a good job at developing nice extensions. However, a useful documentation is not always at the meeting point... and unless reading tons of source code, the (bad) *trial and error* method is what is left for us.

Comment: (btw it seems the 1.9.11 / 2.1.0 versions are available)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at JSON, but you can try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupDiff {
    private List<Integer> addList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> removeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public List<Integer> getAddList() {
        return addList;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRemoveList() {
        return removeList;
    }

    public void setAddList(int... toAdd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++) {
            this.addList.add(toAdd[i]);
        }
    }

    public void setRemoveList(int... toRemove) {
        for (int i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
            this.removeList.add(toRemove[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupDiff groupDiff;

        /*
         * All of this calls will work good.
         */
        groupDiff = new GroupDiff();
        groupDiff.setAddList(10);
        groupDiff.setRemoveList(100);
        System.out.printf("addList=%s; removeList=%s\n", 
                groupDiff.addList, groupDiff.removeList);

        groupDiff = new GroupDiff();
        groupDiff.setAddList(10, 11, 12, 13);
        groupDiff.setRemoveList(100);
        System.out.printf("addList=%s; removeList=%s\n", 
                groupDiff.addList, groupDiff.removeList);

        groupDiff = new GroupDiff();
        groupDiff.setAddList(new int[]{10, 11, 12, 13});
        groupDiff.setRemoveList(100);
        System.out.printf("addList=%s; removeList=%s\n", 
                groupDiff.addList, groupDiff.removeList);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
addList=[10]; removeList=[100]
addList=[10, 11, 12, 13]; removeList=[100]
addList=[10, 11, 12, 13]; removeList=[100]
```

Comment: thank you. I tried it but it doesn't work. I'm going to use the solution proposed by emka86.